# IE is adding styles to background image style

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background, background-image

I have attached a screen shot below of a recreation of an issue. For some reason when I have a background image style IE8 is taking another style from the same selector and appending it after the background-image style. This is causing issues on some of my pages.

My HTML is simply:

```
<div>test</div>
```

My CSS (in the head tag) is:

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
background-image:url("breadcrumb_location.jpg");
border: 1px solid green;
font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
</style>
```

And here you can see the developer tool in IE8, why is the border showing up at the end of the same line for the background image style? As a workaround, I know I can just make a separate selector ( such as div{background-image:url("some-image.jpg");} ) but I don't want to have to do this all over.

[image: Screen shot of web developer tool in IE8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this bug goes away if I use the complete background shorthand. This is also not an ideal solution because there are many background images on my pages and ultimately it is adding what I consider unnecessary css resulting in a larger css file (yes, every bit counts, especially when you might have hundreds or more background images in a css file for a whole site.)

Anyway, unless anyone can suggest a better fix for this bug (and in case anyone else doesn't know CSS shorthand), the fix was changing background-image to:

```
background: white url("breadcrumb_location.jpg") no-repeat top left;
```

Comment: Interesting find, I was able to recreate it on my machine as well (unfortunately i too support IE8) I wouldn't consider this to be adding unecessary styles tho. The dev tool shows you all Border-* styles broken out regardless. I would think this is a bug with the dev tools not the css. I'm not certain so dont hate too much, but I would think your previous shorthand would be fine to leave as is.

Comment: In the example I gave it is sticking the border on the end. The **real** trouble is another place where it was stick width on the end and that was causing a problem. If it hadn't, I never would have gone snooping for the bug. I post my answer above in the hopes that it will save others from banging their heads against their keyboards too hard :)